# What is the meaning of "on parole" in this text?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Under these circumstances, Isaac, the Metropolitan of Armenia, proceeded to the court of Ctesiphon, and petitioned Isdigerd to replace on the Armenian throne the prince who had been deposed twenty-one years earlier, and who was still a prisoner **on parole** in the "Castle of Oblivion"—viz. Chosroes.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: Have you looked up the word [parole](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/parole) in a dictionary?

Comment: @EddieKal "A promise or undertaking given by a prisoner of war not to escape or, if released, not to engage in hostilities, or to return to custody under stated conditions." ?

Comment: So - the prince had given such an undertaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. What is the meaning of “on parole” in this text?

In this context it means "**promised not to escape**" it is rather archaic and was used mainly by the aristocracy during the medieval period when Knights put a high value on honour, kindness, and courage. There were different terms of parole related to in what conditions the parolee was kept. If he had been released  "not to engage in hostilities, and/or to return to custody under stated conditions." The term of parole was usually ended with the payment of ransom or when some other penalty was met.

---

Under these circumstances, Isaac, the Metropolitan of Armenia, proceeded to the court of Ctesiphon, and petitioned Isdigerd to replace on the Armenian throne the prince who had been deposed twenty-one years earlier, and **who had promised not to escape from his captivity** in the "Castle of Oblivion"—viz. Chosroes.

---

**Definition of parole**
a promise made with or confirmed by a pledge of one's honor
especially : the promise of a prisoner of war to fulfill stated conditions in consideration of his release

Ref MERRIAM-WEBSTER [**Parole**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parole)